# Add every word in array with - symbol

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using wp_post_terms_array to output taxanomy terms, here is the code:

```
$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'amenity', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if($post_terms){
   foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
      echo '<li class="icon-'.strtolower($term).'">'.$term.'</li>';
   }
}
```

i want every word from the output of the $term to be connected with - symbol.

For example:

Private Pool to Private-Pool

Private Gym to Private-Gym

Thanks

Comment: why not use `str_replace(' ','-', $term)`

Comment: Try `str_replace(" ","-",$term);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you're using Wordpress, the correct function is [`sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)

Example:

```
<?php
$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'amenity', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if($post_terms){
   foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
      $term = sanitize_title($term);
      echo '<li class="icon-'.$term.'">'.$term.'</li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: @SajjadAhmad Check whatelse [sanitize_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) do. I guess you don't need a wordpress specific function to just replace `space` with `hyphen`

Comment: True, because `sanitize_title` will remove accents.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is `str_replace()`, use like so:

```
$term = str_replace(" ","-",$term);
```

[See PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the spaces with a hyphen with str_replace....

```
$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'amenity', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if($post_terms){
   foreach ( $post_terms as $term ) {
      echo '<li class="icon-'.strtolower($term).'">'.str_replace(" ","-",$term).'</li>';
   }
}
```